# Create table for n:m relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, join, relationship

I have a question about MySQL. I have this table:

```
ID      Name
------  ------------
1       Peter
2       John
3       Carl
4       William
```

The records are linked according to this table:

```
Name          LinkedName
------------  --------------
Peter         Carl
Peter         William
Carl          John
```

I.e. 
- Peter is related to Carl and William
- Carl is related to John

Based on that table, how do I create this:

```
ID1     ID2
------  ------------
1       3
1       4
3       2
```

I have tried to use two JOINs e.g.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM PersonLinks T 
       JOIN Persons W 
          ON T.Name = W.Word 
       JOIN Persons W2 
          ON T.LinkedName = W2.Word;
```

but my server doesn't respond after such a query.
I really hope that somebody can help me here. Thanks.

Comment: SELECT * FROM `PersonLinks` T
JOIN `Persons` W ON T.Name = W.Word
JOIN `Persons` W2 ON T.LinkedName = W2.Word

Answer (score 2):

Consider the first table with ID and Names is called Names and the second one with relations is called LinkedName.

You should use the following query:

```
SELECT N1.ID AS ID1, N2.ID AS ID2
FROM @LinkedNames LN
LEFT OUTER JOIN @Names N1 ON N1.Name = LN.Name
LEFT OUTER JOIN @Names N2 ON N2.Name = LN.LinkedName
```

This has been tested to give the correct result.

Comment: Thanks. It is just really slow. Maybe simply bacause of the size of the tables. LinkedNames contains 2 million record and Names contains 300.000.

Comment: It takes 10 secs for 50 records. I.e. 5 days for 2 million records.

Comment: If performance is an issue, you need to add indices to the columns most used in the where clause

Comment: @user979719: Check `CREATE INDEX` and `ALTER TABLE` syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-index.html

Comment: Creating the indexes will take some time for this size - but not days anyway - and you only do that once.

Comment: I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose first table with ID and Names is called emp and the second one with relationship is called link.

```
select emp_instance1.id,emp_instance2.id 
  from emp emp_instance1,
       emp emp_instance2,
       link link1 
 where link1.name=emp_instance1.name 
       AND link1.link=emp_instance2.name;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to be even slower.